# How to get index when looping over object in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using objects for data for faster access. To render the data as a list I am using map function from lodash. Inside the function I only have the key and value available. I wish to display the index of current item, for that I have done this [this way](https://jsfiddle.net/nandwana92/2a0p0e55/1/). Is there a different/better way to do this?

**Code Snippet**

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {
        'Rajasthan': 'Jaipur',
        'Tamilnadu': 'Chennai',
        'Maharashtra': 'Mumbai' 
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    let count = 0;

    return (
      <div>
        {
          _.map(this.state.data, (value, key, list, index) => {
            return (
              <div><span>{++count}.</span><span>State: {key}, Capital: {value}</span></div>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }

}

React.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
.widget {
  width: 202px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  //    border:1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.name {
  color: red;
}

.default-label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 180px;
}

.green-label {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 180px;
}

.default-input {
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 180px;
}

.important-input {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 180px;
}

img.center {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.5/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.5/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by `index` while looping over objects? Object have keys and not indexes

Comment: You need to put the code as part of your question.

Comment: @ToddChaffee Was trying to do it, but was struggling with formatting it properly.

Comment: @Rajesh From index, I meant I want to show the serial number of the item in the list as you can see in the fiddle output.

Comment: Objects are inherently *unordered*. The key **is** the index.

Comment: @Rajesh Yes it works fine, just wanted to know if there is a better or different way to do the same.

Comment: @Rajesh I have mentioned this in the last line.

Comment: Sorry Missed that. Also I guess this is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create map of your objects by some `"key"` from you objects. You can use `_.keyBy` From lodash. Then you will have object where property name will be you keys and value will be you full objects. then take it like this `newObject["some key"]`

Answer (score 0):

Lodash offers a battle-tested and efficient implementation of methods for iterating collections (both arrays and objects). However, if you would like to do it with plain Javascript, you can do it by using `Object.keys(yourObject)`, that returns an array of the object keys. To achieve the same result:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {
        'Rajasthan': 'Jaipur',
        'Tamilnadu': 'Chennai',
        'Maharashtra': 'Mumbai'
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    let count = 0;

    return (
      <div>
        {
          Object.keys(this.state.data).forEach(key => {
            return (
              <div><span>{++count}.</span><span>State: {key}, Capital: {this.state.data[key]}</span></div>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }

}

React.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change your data type with this

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     data: [{
    key: 'Rajasthan',
    value: 'Jaipur'
  },
  {
    key: 'Tamilnadu',
    value: 'Chennai',
  },
  {
    key: 'Maharashtra',
    value: 'Mumbai',
  }
    ]
    };
```

and you can be organized easy

```
   this.state.data.map((item,index) => {
        return (
          <div><span>{index}</span><span>State: {item.key}, Capital: {item.value}</span></div>
        );
      })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nandwana92/2a0p0e55/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` in order to get your data keys and loop through them like so:

```
  Object.keys(this.state.data).map((val, index) => {
    return (
        <p key={this.state.data[val]}>
        {'index: ' + index} {'key: ' + val + ' ' + ' Value: '  + this.state.data[val]}
      </p>
    )
  })
```

should output:

// index: 0 key: Rajasthan Value: Jaipur

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do it, using `ol`.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {
        'Rajasthan': 'Jaipur',
        'Tamilnadu': 'Chennai',
        'Maharashtra': 'Mumbai' 
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    let count = 0;

    return (
      <ol>
        {Object.entries(this.state.data).map(([key, value]) => <li>State: {key}, Capital: {value}</li>) }
      </ol>
    );
  }

}

React.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
.widget {
  width: 202px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  //    border:1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.name {
  color: red;
}

.default-label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 180px;
}

.green-label {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 180px;
}

.default-input {
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 180px;
}

.important-input {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 180px;
}

img.center {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.5/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.5/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```